# iOS storyboard AutoLayout and adding constraint

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios7

I am making changes to my app to support 3.5″ display. Currently it is supporting 4″ display. 
The screen layout looks like this. How to add following constraint in storyboard ? (I have enabled auto layout option in storyboard.)

1. How to set button1 & button2 width to the half of super view's width ? and both should intersect at the middle of the superview's width.
2. UIImage #1 should be placed at the middle of the superview's width.

[image: StoryboardView]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## 1 : Buttons

*Didn't figure to do everything in interface builder*

You've got to declare an `NSLayoutConstraint` outlet in  your code :

`@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet NSLayoutConstraint *buttonWidthConstraint;`

and then set :

`self.buttonWidthConstraint.constant = self.containerView.frame.size.width /2;`

Here is  what you have to do in IB :

- The 2 buttons must have the same width.

[image: First image]

- For both buttons, stick them to the left and right, and bottom, and fix their height like this :

[image: Second image]

## 2 : Center image view

Center the image view like this

[image: center image view]

Fix it's width, height, and **Y position**

[image: fix width height]

Hope this helps.

Comment: You can simply add a width constraint (in IB) from the button to the container view with the multiplier being 1:2 (or 0.5) to achieve the 'half width' constraint.