# Proportions on iOS Simulator do not match design in Storyboard

Tags: ios, objective-c

I do get a mismatch between the view controllers I see in my storyboard and the result when I run it in the simulator. 
I've been looking for a way to fix this for a while, but didn't find any answer working for me. Please check out the attached images for a clearer picture:
[image: This is how it looks on the storyboard]

[image: The selected size of the device]

[image: The iOS Simulator result]

Comment: This is because of applied constraints in your storyboard. You should apply "Horizontal Center in container constrains" for this. Please check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23884291/ios-storyboard-autolayout-and-adding-constraint

Comment: set the constraint of textfield to trailing, leading and top to the superview

Comment: @Student thanks for your link, but - and this is still confusing me in general - this solution provides a rather static approach, right? So if screen sizes differ, for example from an iPhone 5 to 6, won't the layout be screwed up?

Comment: @AshishKakkad thanks man, in the end, this was it. Do you have a link though where someone actually sets a top constraint to the superview? I was able to manage left and right auto constraint using the auto layout issue menu (looks like this in the story board editor: |-/\-) |

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to add constraints to your textfield

1. Select textfield
2. Select 'Pin' button (it looks like |-[]-| ) at the right bottom corner of your storyboard
   [image]
3. Add constraints

[image]

After that, when you select you textfield it should look like this

[image]

Comment: Hi @Doro thanks for your answer! Basically I agree with your approach, but isn't that very static and limiting my view to a certain device? Of course this can be a trade off, but it would be very frustrating to do this already at a single text field? Also I tried your solution, but I makes me wonder if my environment is set up correctly, please check out my process and its result: [link] (https://drive.google.com/folderview?id=0BzCrSkxjPkzFfnY2dWl2SWZHU3hpOWpiZUhpa0RhbmRXOTJseFNvZFRQMU5SM05wdkY0cnc&usp=sharing)

Comment: You've added wrong constraint at  bottom of your textfield - you should 'fix' it's height in order to work it correctly. what you actually did - you set constraints to automatically scale when view changes subview. check out my answer - i've added 'Height' constraint, not bottom. and, of course, you must set constraints for all your elements at your stroyboard, but you can select several elements to set identical constraints

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that `width: compact | height: regular` does not match the screen size of the simulator you are using. Either use auto-layout's constraints or set the UIObjects' positions programmatically.

Hope that helps :)

Comment: Hi Linus G. , thanks for your answer. My simulator is an iphone 6 simulator and since width: compact | height: regular  should cover every iPhone model https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BzCrSkxjPkzFSi1vTnprajBrZzQ/view?usp=sharing  , this should me a problem, or do I just get this it wrong?