# Cannot get Auto Layout to position elements properly

Tags: ios, autolayout

I'm following Apple's [tutorial](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/referencelibrary/GettingStarted/DevelopiOSAppsSwift/BuildABasicUI.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40015214-CH5-SW2) on iOS development. I tried to add new constraints with parameters from tutorial, but elements are moved to the right side of storyboard while width and height remains unchanged.

[image]

I'm using iPhone 7 in interface designer just like tutorial says.

Comment: Look at the following solution: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23884291/ios-storyboard-autolayout-and-adding-constraint

Comment: I can help you out if you could tell how you want the UI elements to appear? But one thing whenever you give constraint to an element, it will take with respect to its superview. Ex- leading space 10 means from 10pt from its immediate superview.

Comment: @Mansi The same way it's showed in tutorial.

Answer (score 0):

Depends on what you intend on doing, let's say you want to get all the elements to the right side , you would need to modify constraints for that. If you want to modify alignment or size or spacing of elements in a stackView I recommend you check content hugging and content compression resistance priority.

Answer (score 0):

@Nikola, sometimes if constraint does not work properly, first thing should be done is clear all constraint :) (clear constraint available if you click on triangular symbol at right bottom corner). In your case, choose any size class.Then give 4 constraint to stack view -leading constraint, top space, height and width to stack view w.r.t. view controller's view.Then give constraint to each element of stack view. Give leading space and top space w.r.t to stack view to the top most element (Meal Name label)of stack view. Then the other two element give leading space as well as a top space to the immediate above element. I have explained one of a way to display the element with min constraint. With these many constraint, you should be able to see the elements in the correct position. I have not mention about the height width of element because that is upto you to give the required size. Lets see whether this will resolve your issue or not..